# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/commonroom/resources/views/home.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

## App\Classes

```
public function enroll()
{
return $this->hasMany(Enrolls::class,'cid');
}
```

## App\Enrolls

```
public function classes()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Classes::class);
}
```

## controller

```
public function index()
{
$enrolls = Enrolls::all();
return view('home')->with('enrolls', $enrolls);
}
```

## blade

```
{{$enroll->classes->title}}
```

> I was trying to get data from enrolls table. this contains two foreign Keys.

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Could you post a var_dump of your `$enroll` variable?

Comment: @AlbertoGuilherme i can't post var_dump during some *** issue on stack overflow

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
public function index()
{
   $enrolls = Enrolls::with('classes')->get();
   return view('home',compact('enrolls'));
}
```